# Serving static content with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been following a couple of tutorials on serving static files (CSS, JS etc.) using Spring and from what I can see I should be able to see my static files but I can't.

My `spring-web-servlet.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="brass.ducks" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="views" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

The last line suggests that any URL that follows `styles/whatever.css` should look in my views folder and serve from there. For example my page has a link to a stylesheet as `/styles/css/bootstrap.min.css` (which would complete to `http://localhost:8080/Brass-Ducks/styles/css/bootstrap.min.css`) but this does not resolve to my style sheet.

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

As suggested I extracted my `.war` file and found the folder hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

I've modified my `web.xml` to look like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

But the URL `http://localhost:8080/Brass-Ducks/styles/css/bootstrap.min.css` still does not resolve a CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `styles` directory to `/webapp/resourses` path. So you will have `/webapp/resourses/styles`. Change xml config with `<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/resources/styles/"` and try to get from `http://localhost:8080/Brass-Ducks/styles/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping config to:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/styles/" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are missing the `/`, it should look like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/views/" />
```

and XML is not really a good idea to configure spring, try java config..

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/Brass-Ducks/styles/css/bootstrap.min.css` still does not show the stylesheet.

Comment: @Nanor open your `war` file with file browser, checkout if it is there. and there response is `404`?

Comment: I can see my `.war` file in my file browser but I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: @Nanor check if the response is `404`, extract your war file and see if the resource is in the correct path